# How to Upload file to google drive from strapi in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

Is there any documentation for how we can upload file to Google drive using Strapi?

Answer (score 1):

Does this help you?

https://medium.com/easyread/changes-storage-destination-from-local-disk-into-google-cloud-storage-in-strapi-v4-bad6e41e14a0

Checkout this package too:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-provider-upload-google-drive